# Using delimeter to seperate Scanner input into different dataTypes.(String, int,

Tags: delimiter

how can i use delimiter " : " to receive a string from (system.in ) E.g Ben : 50. Jessica : 30 and so on , and then print as Ben, 50 using my own System.out.print (name + "," + score); I was able to print out the string as string but its not printing out the integer as integer.  I need to calculate the average of all the score and  that is  why i need integer to remain integer so the average method can work Here is my code .  Here is my code so far. Please help !!!

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentScore{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  input.useDelimiter(":"); 
    System.out.print("Please enter your name and score in format: Ben : 50" );

String name = input.next();
int score = input.nextInt();
while(input.hasNext() || input.hasNextInt());{
System.out.println(name + ", " + score);
}

  input.close();
  }





  }
```

this keeps creeating a new scanner and no print out.

Answer (score 0):

After researching and asking several people , i found  out the String class actually has a function that takes in string and then splits it into several primitive values" long", " int" and so on. You need to convert your input into an  array, make sure it is spitted by a delimiter of choice .e.g "," or  ":" in my own case. Then the array will be your parameter for the .split method from the String  class. I posted my complete program below.  The programs takes in three names and score and outputs the grade letter and then tells the best score among the three students.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreeNamesAndScore {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your name and score in this format, Name : Score");
        String input1 = input.nextLine();
        String[] userData1 = input1.split(":");
        String firstStudentName = userData1[0];
        String firstStudentStrScore = userData1[1];
        int firstStudentScore = Integer.parseInt(firstStudentStrScore);
        System.out.print("Please enter your name and score in this format, Name : Score");

        String input2 = input.nextLine();
        String[] userData2 = input2.split(":");
        String secondStudentName = userData2[0];
        String secondStudentStrScore = userData2[1];
        int secondStudentScore = Integer.parseInt(secondStudentStrScore);
        System.out.print("Please enter your name and score in this format, Name : Score");

        String input3 = input.nextLine();
        String[] userData3 = input3.split(":");
        String thirdStudentName = userData3[0];
        String thirdStudentStrScore = userData3[1];
        int thirdStudentScore = Integer.parseInt(thirdStudentStrScore);

        System.out.println("The following is the fianl result ");
        System.out.println(firstStudentName + ", " + getGradeLetter(firstStudentScore));
        System.out.println(secondStudentName + ", " + getGradeLetter(secondStudentScore));
        System.out.println(thirdStudentName + ", " + getGradeLetter(thirdStudentScore));

        System.out.println("The best score is from " + bestScore(input1, input2, input3));
        input.close();
    }

    public static String getGradeLetter(int score) {

        if (score >= 90) {
            return "A";
        } else if (score >= 80) {
            return "B";
        } else if (score >= 70) {
            return "C";
        } else if (score >= 60) {
            return "D";
        } else
            return "F";

    }

    public static String bestScore(String a, String b, String c) {
        String bestStudent;
        String[] userInputs = { a, b, c };
        String[] user1 = a.split(":");

        String aStrScore = user1[1];
        int aScore = Integer.parseInt(aStrScore);
        String[] user2 = b.split(":");

        String bStrScore = user2[1];
        int bScore = Integer.parseInt(bStrScore);
        String[] user3 = c.split(":");

        String cStrScore = user3[1];
        int cScore = Integer.parseInt(cStrScore);

        if ((aScore > bScore) && (aScore > cScore))
            bestStudent = a;
        else if ((bScore > aScore) && (bScore > cScore))
            bestStudent = b;
        else
            bestStudent = c;

        return bestStudent;
    }
}
```